# How can I pass parameters to `cursor.execute` in `pymssql`?

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I am connecting to sql server db via `pymssql` library. And I am trying to use the method `cursor.execute(sql, params)` to execute query.

```
sql = """
            SELECT
                MIN(myDate)
            FROM
                %s
        """
```

The sql statement is defined above. It simply selects the minimum date value from the table.

when I run below code to pass the parameter:

```
cursor.execute(sql, 'Daily')
```

I got this error `pymssql.ProgrammingError: (102, b"Incorrect syntax near 'Daily'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")`.

I wonder how the parameter should be passed to the sql statement?

After some debugging I found the issue relates to the table name. It looks like I can't put table name in the parameter. The reason I don't want to concentrate the sql string is to avoid sql injection. Is there a way to pass the table name as a parameter?

Comment: This `cursor.execute(sql, ('Daily',))`?

Comment: No it doesn't work. Still got syntax error

Comment: This does not work. You can't pass literals like table or column names as parameters. The `psycopg2` PostgreSQL driver provides a special package to safely compose SQL strings, but to my knowledge no other driver offers something similar. You'll have to carefully sanitize table and column names yourself and put them into the query via string concatenation or interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

May be your query is including `\n`.

Repalce `\n` with space(`' '`)

Try this,

```
sql = """
            SELECT
                MIN(myDate)
            FROM
                %s
        """
cursor.execute(sql.replace('\n',' '), ('Daily',))
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't help. Same syntax error.

Comment: @ZhaoYi Can you please add complete `traceback` to question?